# How to display multiple addresses on a single map

Tags: here-api

I have a list of Lat and Longs that I would like to display as points/markers on a map.  How do I do this.  I have been able to do one address using geocodingParams option, but can't see how to do it with multiples.  I will have a list of addresses that I would like to geocode and display or I can convert addresses to lat/long and then display.  I'm very new to this as you can tell!
Thanks for any help you may be able to give this newbie.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the documentation. There's an example for putting multiple markers on the map: https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/maps-js/v3.0/markers/markers-on-the-map